# HHmm regular expression validation

Tags: regex

I need to validate HHmm using regex expression.
below is my code
([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3])[0-5][0-9]

which is validating fine for 
24:20
12:59
and fails for 12:60 and 2400
also it is passing 123 and 127, 128..
i need two digits for minutes, even 1 digit also it is taking.

How can i avoid that.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: [demo](http://regex101.com/r/jU1zW4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define boundaries for your regex. With those, you are sure it won't simply match `4:20` in the string `24:20`. So, with that, it would be this:

```
\b([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3])[0-5][0-9]\b
```

[**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/wQ2uT4)

The other change I've made is: I've merged `[0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]` to a shorter `[01]?[0-9]`.

If you want to match a HH:mm format instead, you should simply place a `:` in the middle of it:

```
\b([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]\b
```

[**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/kQ1hT2)

---

And if you want to restrict the match for 4-digit timestamps (so not 159 but 0159 only), you should simply remove the `?` in that expression:

```
\b([01][0-9]|2[0-3])[0-5][0-9]\b
```

[**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/rS0tQ2)

Comment: HI,using the above one also ,127 is passing, i dont need to pass this

Comment: @user2979719 what do you mean exactly?

Comment: i don't need to pass 127, i only need to pass hhmm not hhm and that too 127 should not be passed.

Comment: See the third demo for that. Does that do what you want? You can test it for yourself by modifying the text in the demo.